# How to check if the user speak to the microphone?

Tags: c#-4.0, audio, unity-game-engine, microphone

I want to check if the user speak to the microphone. I've tried  but it didn't work. How can I achieve this?

My code is:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour 
{
    AudioClip sound;
    string dname;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        foreach(string device in Microphone.devices)
        {
            dname=device;
        }
        sound=Microphone.Start(dname,true,10, 44100);
        //here check user speak to microphone or not.
    }
}
```

Comment: Would have been helpfull to list what libraries you have tried, what the effect of those were and why it didn't work. You can expect answers you have already tried, wasting both the answerer and your time...

Comment: And as for your question, a few explanations are found here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/137170/how-to-check-if-the-user-speak-to-microphone.html It shortly says there are a few tricks to achieve what you want, but it's a workaround and messy. You're advised to either wait untill Unity3d implements some kind of API, or to use an other IDE.

Comment: I'm not sure what library you're using, however in my experience, the system default microphone is always listed first in the system's device list. You seem to be using the last device in the list (after the foreach). Maybe try using device[0]?